# Updating URL without redirection is not working

Tags: javascript, url

I have tried `window.history.pushState('', '', site_url + '' + ActivityUrl);` and also `window.history.replaceState('', '', site_url + '' + ActivityUrl);`

I need to update the URL in the browser without redirecting to it. All the solutions I had got are the above two, but this is not working and also not displaying any errors.

The code I'm using is in an AngularJS controller,

```
$scope.updateUrl = function (ActivityUrl) {

    window.history.pushState('', '', site_url + '' + ActivityUrl);
}
```

and calling this function with a ng-click.

Comment: AngularJS or Angular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, you need to set the configuration for the location provider:

```
// Configure $locationProvider html5Mode
app.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true, requireBase: false, rewriteLinks: false });
}]);
```

And then change your method as:

```
$scope.updateUrl = function (ActivityUrl) {
    $window.history.pushState('', '', site_url + '' + ActivityUrl);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @sapna-Bhayal. this works and i got what i needed.

Comment: I still got a question, when my url gets changed, the page doesn't redirects  that's good.  But if i reload the page it goes to the new url, that's also fine but now if i click on browser's back button the url only gets changed the page remains the same.  Is their any way i can redirect to previous page after reload. just as a normal back event.???